# Want to change dutyCycle parameter value dynamically during run time in TunableMAC.CC in castalia simulator

Tags: simulation, omnet++

I am working with the Castalia simulator and I am trying to do some modification in TunableMAC.CC file under MAC directory. My intention is the sleepingInterval (Duration of sleeping) of node should not be same in execution of entire simulation.

According to my understanding in TunableMAC.cc module, the dutyCycle value we are providing in omnetpp.ini is assigned to dutyCycle parameter in startup() method and remains the same during entire execution of simulation.

I do not want static dutyCycle value for my entire simulation.

Answer (score 1):

The [Castalia User's Manual](https://github.com/boulis/Castalia/) already describes how you can dynamically change several MAC and radio parameters including dutyCycle.

Read section 4.3.1.1 Dynamically adjusting Tunable MAC parameters from the application module.